# Automapper Include in correct order

Tags: .net, automapper

The Include is a fantactic feature. But in our application mapping configuration is built automatically, gathering all existing classes which have some special property. In short, all mappings are added to configuration in random order.
It can happen that some mapping expression having Include() (which means "use this expression for source/destination descendants") goes after the descendants configuration was added and thus this instruction is not actually appliled :(
Is there a way to force overall configuration to rebuild in a correct order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, experimentally found that if use only IncludeBase<>() (not Include()) for inherited mappers then no matter in what order they all are added into configuration. In short - use IncludeBase bravely!

Answer (score 2):

With AutoMapper 5.0, the order does not matter anymore. It's releasing today (Jun 27th).